# Can't increase partition size with GParted?

Tags: partition, gparted, gpt

I've got an external disk with 6 partitions: 4 for linux, one storage in HFS+, and one storage in ext4. I'd like to delete the ext4 storage one and move it's resulting unallocated space into my HFS+ one, but in GParted, I delete the ext4, and it becomes unallocated. But when I try to resize my HFS+, I can't enter a new value for "New size (MiB)", and the up arrow for it's size is disabled. How can I do this?

My partitions:

```
/dev/sdb1 ext4 /boot 476.84 MiB
/dev/sdb2 linux-swap 1.86 GiB
/dev/sdb3 ext4 / 9.31 GiB
/dev/sdb4 ext4 /home 46.57 GiB
/dev/sdb5 hfs+ SodiumOxide 523.32 GiB (89.81 used, 433.51 unused)
/dev/sdb6 ext4 WiiMC 14.65 GiB (5.36 used, 9.29 unused)
```

I'd like to delete sdb6 and add it's resulting unallocated space to sdb5 (SodiumOxide)

Comment: There are multiple reasons on why this would happen. Could you please post you exact partition structure?

Comment: @darnir added partition info.

Comment: Which partitions are logical? as there are > 4

Comment: @shutupsquare With DOS partitions, partitions 1–4 are always primary or extended and partitions ≥5 are always logical. Since there's no extended partition here, I guess this is disk uses the newer [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't enlarge it with GParted because it currently does not support HFS+ partition "grow". It only supports HFS+ "shrink". See

[Gparted features](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/features.php)

or, on your machine:

*GParted >> View >> File System Support*

Comment: So with this being my only hard drive of size, I'm stuck with the lost space? Could I change it to ext4 or something, increase it, and convert it back?

Comment: Filesystems conversion is generally not possible without data loss, except for filesystems belonging to the same family, e.g. converting ext2 to ext3, ext3 to ext4. I think your best option would be to backup your data on another medium, delete the aforementioned partition and recreate it as per your needs and then restore your data.

Comment: OK. So I can back it up, delete the HFS+, and make new HFS+ with all unallocated space?

Comment: Yes. Make sure you have **hfsprogs** installed.